# null is not an Object (evaluating '_nativeInterface.default.getPhotos') in Cameraroll in react native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-navigation, react-native-camera, react-native-community-netinfo

Using camera roll library from react native community and import correctly named.
Below is the code for same using expo directory to init the project

```
import { ActionSheetIOS, ListView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Platform} from 'react-native';
import { Navigator } from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';
import PhotoBrowser from 'react-native-photo-browser';
import CameraRoll from "@react-native-community/cameraroll";


const Photos= [
  {
    title: 'A',
    description: 'Photo to display',
    enableGrid: false,
    media: [{
      photo: 'A',
      title: 'A',
    }],
  }
];


CameraRoll.getPhotos({
  first: 30,
  assetType: 'Photos',
}).then((data) => {
  const media = [];
  data.edges.forEach(d => media.push({
    photo: d.node.image.uri,
  }));
  Photos[2].media = media;
}).catch();
```

Please suggest to resolve above issue, thank you

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

For me manually linking the Module did the job. `react-native link @react-native-community/cameraroll`